# PHP retornando parse error syntax

Tags: php

ao criar um arquivo php ocorre este erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Marcos\aprendizado1.php on line 30
```

aprendizado1.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>TESTE BASICO PHP</title>
 <style>

 </style>
</head>

<script>

</script>

<body>

        <?php
            header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", true);

            //meus dados

            $nome = "Marcos Antônio";
            $idade = 21;
            $altura = 1.60;

            echo "Meu nome é: $nome, minha idade é: $idade e minha altura é de : $altura";

            <br>

            //alterando meus dados

            $nome = "Felipe Cabral";
            $idade = 30;
            $altura = 1.80;

            echo "Meu nome é: $nome, minha idade é: $idade e minha altura é de : $altura";

            <br>

            echo "<hr>";

            $carro = "Hilux";

            echo $carro;

            //nomes validos



        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O seu '< br >' tem que ficar dentro das aspas do echo.

Fica assim oh:

TESTE BASICO PHP

```
    <?php
        header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", true);

        //meus dados

        $nome = "Marcos Antônio";
        $idade = 21;
        $altura = 1.60;

        echo "Meu nome é: $nome, minha idade é: $idade e minha altura é de : $altura<br>";



        //alterando meus dados

        $nome = "Felipe Cabral";
        $idade = 30;
        $altura = 1.80;

        echo "Meu nome é: $nome, minha idade é: $idade e minha altura é de : $altura <br>";



        echo "<hr>";

        $carro = "Hilux";

        echo $carro;

        //nomes validos



    ?>
```